# Scanning Software for high volume scanning

Tags: document-management

This question is partly programming partly discussion.

We are looking at redeveloping an application which scans documents. Currently there is a back-end component a bunch of DLL files that are drivers etc. between scanner and our software. We need something similar or better that can perform the below tasks. In the mean time I am doing google searches, but if anyone has come across a workable version and has implemented it - that would be even better.

- Is compatible with high volume scanners
- Can detect a barcode (or a number of barcodes on a form)
- Has the ability to output in different file formats
- OCR
- Easy navigation between documents/batches
- Way of seperating different pages etc (i.e. when scanning forms, they are different forms but may be 100 pages worth.) Make it easy for the forms to be scanned - then delivered to a data entry task list for the operator to data enter them, or attach them to a customer.
- Has a well-documented library that can be bolted onto other applications. As we are using this scanning utility, it needs to be able to talk to our application that we are developing. i.e. our application can invoke a scan command (or through its own user interface), and for that information to be passed to our application for data entry.

I know some of the above items may contradict, but this is more or less a wish list for the future software that we use for scanning.

Step 1 - take forms and scan them. At this stage - not much is entered apart from date of receiving documents, date of scanning and a way of identifying each form. I.e. we give it a special number so that we can uniquely identify it. This is also a bar-code. This number/letter combo can be picked up automatically because it is bar-coded before it is scanned. If the scanner cannot recognise the barcode (which is required) it should pause - ask operator to visually verify and enter this piece of information.

Step 2 - This document with the information provided goes to the data entry list, where the information on the form is entered into the system and the information flows on from there.

Thanks,

Dalibor

EDIT:

Other important things include

Comment: Do you care about operating system?

Comment: Yes - Sorry. We are using Windows 8 at the moment - and shall continue to do so into the future. We just upgraded and our next scheduled update for the OS is in 4 to 5 years. So will be using Windows 8 for the foreseeable future. We are in the process of doing analysis for the software program that we are re-designing and rebuilding. Hence the need for an upgrade in the scanning software.

Comment: The list that I have at the moment by doing google research includes ABBYY Scan Station, IRISLink and EverSuite. With our current app we are using PixTools which is well outdated as far as I know.

Comment: Any cost limitations?